# mysql doesnt have write access in data dir?

Tags: mysql-5.5, corruption

I am running a MySQL on my Windows 7 64 bit development machine at work and I can't seem to get around a database corruption issue. In my unit tests it is telling me that the storage engine (which is innodb) is issuing an error message of -1.

In my mysql error log I am reading a log message that says

```
130906 13:31:04  InnoDB: Operating system error number 5 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory. It may also be you have created a subdirectory
InnoDB: of the same name as a data file.
InnoDB: File name .\databaseName\employee_leastfavoriterealnumber.ibd
InnoDB: File operation call: 'create'.
130906 13:31:04  InnoDB: Error creating file '.\databaseName\employee_leastfavoriterealnumber.ibd'.
130906 13:31:04  InnoDB: Operating system error number 5 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory. It may also be you have created a subdirectory
InnoDB: of the same name as a data file.
```

but looking through my file permissions it is showing that both myself and SYSTEM have full access. I have run mysqld from command line as well as from a service, restarted my computer, and even reinstalled mysql in a vain attempt to be able to fix things so I can get back to work. I changed my my.ini file to see if that would fix it.

I am at a loss as to how to fix this? Did I miss something in my my.ini file that I should change? Should I be looking for gremlins mucking around with my user permissions? Is this the beginning of the end?

Comment: The problem is related to UAC I think. Do you have Administrator privileges?

Comment: See this question, too: [Mysql and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1](http://serverfault.com/questions/258388/mysql-and-windows-server-2008-r2-sp1)

Comment: I do believe that I have admin privileges. I have UAC up on my computer and can change what level it is working at.

I have also made sure that the permissions I have set (and I have run mysql as a couple different users) are also set for the files inside the data folder.

Comment: ... and for the data folder and all subfolders? Then, I don't know. But the linked question has an answer that describes how to check which user is the mysql service running under.

Comment: Nope I checked which users mysql was running under. Each account that I have run it under has had Full Access permissions. 

For instance currently I am not running mysql as a service so it is running as my user. Which has full Access privileges.

Comment: maybe the file mysql wants to access are readonly or inherit readonly from parent.

Comment: cause even if you have admin access you need to first change readonly to read/write so you can write to it.

Comment: It is trying to create a new file for creating a table. My understanding is that if full access is given to the folder then that user can do anything they want in there.